# @font-face не удалось пройти проверку на разрешение внедрения шрифтов OpenType

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты, scss

Ребят... ШО IE11 от меня хочет? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**все же подключено, во всех браузерах все норм**

```
$fonts-dir: '../fonts';

@each $file-name, $font-weight, $font-style in
                ('raleway-regular', 400, normal),
                ('raleway-medium', 500, normal),
                ('raleway-semiBold', 600, normal),
                ('raleway-bold', 700, normal), {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-weight: $font-weight;
    font-style: $font-style;
    src: url('#{$fonts-dir}/#{$file-name}.eot');
    src: url('#{$fonts-dir}/#{$file-name}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('#{$fonts-dir}/#{$file-name}.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('#{$fonts-dir}/#{$file-name}.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('#{$fonts-dir}/#{$file-name}.ttf') format('truetype');
  }
}
```

[image: хмммммммммм]

Comment: Попробуйте скачать шрифт из другого места

Comment: Открою вам страшную тайну https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff  .eot не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Нарушение лицензии использования шрифта.
Подробнее о ошибках [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh180764(v=vs.85))